# Why are tree rings the same if rainfall is different from place to place?

Tags: dendrology

I have looked at data from rain gauges and usually the rainfall levels are very different from place to even. Even in adjoining towns or townships the rainfall can exhibit much different patterns.

Nevertheless, all the trees in an area tend to show the same ring patterns. Why is this?

Comment: Those trees show tree rings, is not solely dependent on rainfall. They're dependent on their internal genetic program. Maybe also there are effect of daylight, temperature, etc.

Comment: Maybe not only  the exact-amount of rainfall, rather overall humidity and desiccation rate affect the process.

Answer (score 1):

The rings are not only affected by time but also by location. So no, the patterns are not always the same depending where you are. Climate do affect the rings.

Typically a major factor affecting ring patterns is the seasonality. Depending on the number of rainy season, you might observe one or two rings per year.

If interested, [here is an introduction to dendrochronology](http://www.geog.uvic.ca/dept2/faculty/smithd/477/manuals/techniques/05%20Geog%20477.pdf) (from the University of Victoria).

Comment: I have a whole textbook on dendrochronology. It does not discuss this issue.

Comment: I must say I lack much citation and answer by what I remembered from my Bachelor degree. Citing [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrochronology): `, the variation of the tree-ring growths provides not only a match by year, it can also match location because the climate across a continent is not consistent`. But please, wait for other users input before accepting the answer of someone who knows very little about dendrochronology.

Comment: What is your textbook by the way?

Comment: Fundamentals of Tree-Ring Research by James H. Speer